# How to prevent widget resize on unlock swipe?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.3-jelly-bean

After upgrading to 4.3, there is only a small portion of the lower screen that can be used to unlock the phone.  The upper part of the screen engages what looks like some sort of draw or resize box with a pencil in the lower right corner.  I think it is trying to resize the clock widget for some reason.

This is very annoying since I never want to resize the widgets after they are set, but obviously, I swipe the phone a lot.  Is there a way to disable this box and return the swipe area to the visible window?